# Changing account associated with Kindle

Tags: amazon, kindle

I own a Kindle Touch, the 2012 version, and until recently I had it associated with my someone else's account. However, I now want to change it to my own account, but I've obviously bought various books, collections and also got some dictionaries.

If I change the account, will I lose all of them? I transferred everything to my Calibre application on my computer, but I'm not sure if they'll still remain there after the change.

Anecdotal experiences are fine, but I'd appreciate some official proof on this if you manage to find some.

Answer (score 2):

> If I change the account, will I lose all of them

Yes, you'll retain only those books/magazines in your account

> I transferred everything to my Calibre application on my computer, but I'm not sure if they'll still remain there after the change.

I believe Kindle books are DRM-protected, so Calibre might have the books but may not be able to open them(unless you remove DRM on them).

A workaround would be to add the [older account to your Kindle](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201632870) as part of the new [Kindle Household feature](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201540710)